# Published android app on play store still in early access

Tags: android, google-play-services, release, production, google-developers-console

I rolled out an app which is already in play store but still in early access after 8 days of release. It is an open testing type.
The production status is still inactive even though it is already published.
How can I remove early access? Should I still wait for play store to complete the process?

I have tried a new release but no change.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the Google Play console and try opening your release. If you are able to "elevate" your release and upgrade it to production, the erly Access is omitted. If you release is still being processed, this can take a while. But 8 days seems to be a very long time. If this is your first time  publish, this can be but if not, you could check if all Ressources are there. This is especially relevant if you have set up your Store Entry and and all images are provided.

Please check if there are any warnings or the processing was aborted. This could be your problem regarding the release.

Comment: Thanks. This is my first published app though.

Comment: Do you need any more help? Or is the issue fixed, if this is the case you can mark the answer as solved.

Comment: Not yet solved. Still waiting

Comment: Maybe you should check if there are any warnings. It shouldnt take that long